# yum fails to fetch mirror list 403 Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Edit: seems to be working now. Discussion here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=344200

I'm finding that Amazon Linux yum can not retrieve the mirror list, failing with a 403 error.
Going to http://amazonlinux.default.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list in a browser does indeed produce a 403 error.
This is running from local docker environment, so no S3 VPC endpoint is involved.
What can I do about this?

To reproduce:

`docker run -it --entrypoint bash amazonlinux:latest`

`yum update`

This produces the following:

```
bash-4.2# yum update
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://amazonlinux.default.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was
14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
((truncated long output))

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn2-core/2/x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the files on AWS's S3 bucket at this location have been removed or the access revoked.

This has now been resolved by AWS.